# Reversing list of nodes

Tags: swift

I have the following Node class which points to a next node :

```
class Node<T> {
    var data: T
    var next: Node<T>?

 init(data: T, next: Node<T>?) {
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
    }
}
```

and I wrote a method to reverse the data , for example

```
let list = Node<Int>(data:1,next :Node<Int>(data:2,next :Node<Int>(data :3,next :nil)))
```

which has values 1,2,3 should have values 3,2,1
here is my function :

```
    extension Node {
        func reverse() {

        var firstNode = self
         var previousNode: Node<T>? = nil
        var currentNode = firstNode
        var nextNode = firstNode.next
        while nextNode != nil {

            currentNode.next = previousNode
            previousNode = currentNode
            currentNode = nextNode!
            nextNode = currentNode.next
        }

        currentNode.next = previousNode
        firstNode = currentNode


        var current = firstNode as Node<T>?
       //print 3 2 1
        while(current != nil)
        {
          print(current!.data)
          current = current!.next

        }


        }
    }
```

The printing in the method indeed displays "3 2 1" however, how can I set it to the current object to be the reversed list? Assigning at the end **"self = current"** seems to be prohibited.

Comment: Where do you keep the pointer to the head of the list? It seems, the way it's designed, is that something external holds the pointer, so the reverse function can return a new head (which `firstNode`, in your code)

Comment: there is no head pointer , the goal is when you create such an object and call .reverse() on it , to reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `list` is just a variable of `Node<Int>` - i.e. a pointer to the head node.

You cannot mutate `self` to be a reference to a different node - the tail node in the original list, but you could return the last node and re-assign what `list` points to:

```
var list = Node<Int>(...)

list = list.reverse()
```

The `reverse` function would need to return a `Node<T>` type:

```
func reverse() -> Node<T> {
   // your algorithm
   // ...


   return firstNode
}
```

Btw, your code doesn't account for cycles in the list. If some node points to one of its previous nodes, then your `while nextNode != nil` will become an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have no way to know what your linked list *is*. Add one:

```
class Node<T> : CustomStringConvertible {
    var data: T
    var next: Node<T>?
    init(data: T, next: Node<T>?) {
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
    }
    var description: String {
        var s = ""
        var node = Optional(self)
        while node != nil {
            s.append(String(describing:node!.data))
            node = node?.next
        }
        return(s)
    }
}
```

Now it's easy to see that your `reverse` is working. All you have to do is have it produce *a value.*

```
extension Node {
    func reverse() -> Node? {
        var firstNode = self
        var previousNode: Node<T>? = nil
        var currentNode = firstNode
        var nextNode = firstNode.next
        while nextNode != nil {
            currentNode.next = previousNode
            previousNode = currentNode
            currentNode = nextNode!
            nextNode = currentNode.next
        }
        currentNode.next = previousNode
        firstNode = currentNode
        let current = firstNode as Node<T>?
        return current
    }
}
```

Here's a test:

```
    let list = Node<Int>(data:1,next :Node<Int>(data:2,next :Node<Int>(data :3,next :nil)))
    print(list) // 123
    if let newlist = list.reverse() {
        print(newlist) // 321, yay!
    }
```